# cpp default constructor and member initialization list?

Tags: c++

```
class test
{
public:
    test(int x)
    {
        val = x;
    }
private:
    int val;
};

test t(3);
```

I got 2 points about this code.

1. `test t(3)`would call default constructor first, then do `val = 3`
2. if there is at least a user-defined constructor, then the compiler does not generate an implicit default constructor

is there a contradiction?

Comment: The first point is wrong: The default constructor is *not* called. (There is no default constructor.)

Comment: What makes you think a default constructor is called?

Comment: You can easily test it, print some lines to the console to answer your questions.

Comment: 1) no default constructor is available to be called (as you didn't provide one). 2) t(3) is explicitly calling the int x constructor anyway so it wouldn't happen even if there was a default constructor.

Comment: @JosephMansfield misunderstanding a C++ book make me "think a default constructor is called". Sorry for that. thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
test t(3);
```

is calling your parametrized constructor( with argument as 3 ) not default constructor. And yes if you define a single constructor with parameter then compiler won't generate dfault constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> `test t(3)` would call default constructor first, then do `val = 3`

No default constructor is called. `val` is default-initialised before the `test` constructor body; if `val` were a type with a default constructor, then that constructor would be called. But `int` doesn't have a constructor, and default-initialising just leaves it in its uninitialised state with an indeterminate value.

Perhaps you were thinking that this might call the default constructor of `test`. It doesn't; no constructor of `test` would do that, unless you explicitly delegated to that constructor.

> if there is at least a user-defined constructor, then the compiler does not generate an implicit default constructor

That's correct, declaring any constructor prevents the implicit default constructor.

> is there a contradiction?

No. `test` doesn't have a default constructor, but nothing here tries to use such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, custom constructor doesn't call parameterless constructor, so it is not contradiction.

You're probably mixing two things together - every constructor calls a base class constructor (either default, or some else if you specify the arguments).